# insert a variable in a Set in python

Tags: python, list, insert, set, addition

I have a problem with inserting vars in Python sets. Does anyone know what I got:   **s.insert(len(s),x)** ?

My problem is when I wanna **insert** or **add** x into a set or a list.

Why can't I do it? And how to fix this problem?

My code:

```
import nltk
import Set

FILE=open("out.txt", "w")
FILE.writelines("this is to show why using NNs :)!!!!\n")

text1=raw_input()
FILE.writelines("first text loaded.....\n")
sentences1=text1.split('.')
FILE.writelines("first text splited.....\n")

text2=raw_input()
FILE.writelines("second text loaded.....\n")
sentences2=text2.split('.')
FILE.writelines("second text splited.....\n")



s=['a','b']
FILE.writelines("\n NNs for first:\n")
for sen in sentences1:
    tokens1= nltk.word_tokenize(sen)
    tagged1 = nltk.pos_tag(tokens1)
    for (x, y) in tagged1:
        if y=='NN':
            FILE.writelines(x+",")
            s.insert(len(s),x)
FILE.writelines(len(s1))


FILE.writelines("\n NNs for second:\n")
for sen in sentences2:
    tokens2= nltk.word_tokenize(sen)
    tagged2 = nltk.pos_tag(tokens2)
    for (x, y) in tagged2:
        if y=='NN':
            FILE.writelines(x+",")
            s2[len(s2)]= x
FILE.writelines(len(s2))

print "********temoum**********"
FILE.close()
```

Answer (score 22):

When `s` is a list, you can do:

```
s.insert(len(s),x)
```

This means: "insert element `x` into list `s` at position `len(s)`", which means you're inserting the element at the end of the list.

When `s` is a set, you can do:

```
s.add(x)
```

A set has no order so you don't need to specify a position. A set also contains no duplicates, which can be useful if you need it. If not, you can use a list instead.

---

The unexpected IndentationError can be found here:

```
if y=='NN':
    FILE.writelines(x+",")
        s.insert(len(s),x)
```

This should look like this:

```
if y=='NN':
    FILE.writelines(x+",")
    s.insert(len(s),x)
```

Comment: Am I missing something, or is the first just a convoluted way of saying `s.append(c)`?

Comment: it said IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: @delnan: Yes :) The first approach is only useful if you're going to insert at different positions, not always at the end.

Comment: @user1472850: I have updated my answer to show what the code should look like.

Comment: s=['a','b']
FILE.writelines("\n NNs for first:\n")
for sen in sentences1:
    tokens1= nltk.word_tokenize(sen)
    tagged1 = nltk.pos_tag(tokens1)
    for (x, y) in tagged1:
        if y=='NN':
            FILE.writelines(x+",")
                s.insert(len(s),x)
FILE.writelines(len(s1))